# tinymce remove overlay in android webview

Tags: tinymce-4

I used `tinymce` in android app and I want to set `tinymce` editor to show content and after on touch the content should be editable.But it needs `two click`, one for overlay div and one for edit icon.
can you help me.
Thanks.

this is my code in index.html that loaded in android Webview :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="tinymce.js"></script>    
    <script src="tinymce.config.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function init1(data) {        
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data);               
            var a = setInterval(function() {$('.tinymce-mobile-mask-tap-
              icon').trigger('touchstart');$('.tinymce-mobile-mask-tap-
              icon').trigger('touchend');b();}, 2000);
            var b = function(){clearInterval(a);}               
        }   


    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getData(status){
            //return tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
            Android.storeText(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(), status);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <textarea id="txtContent">

        </textarea>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I updated with sharing my code